# React native camera not working as expected with expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera

I want to make a qrcode reader with react native,and i'm using expo.I'm following the guide based on the official documentation here : [react-native-qrcode-scanner](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner#react-native-camera)

I've installed `react-native-camera` succesfully by running `npm install react-native-camera --save` and the following is the commande `react-native link react-native-camera` in the console,and it gives me the following error: [image: Error message]
By reading the doc if find that many things depend on `react-native link` like `react-native link react-native-qrcode-scanner
react-native link react-native-permissions` an also after that there are some configurations like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>` that i cannot do because i don't use `react-native-cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo already has what you want. `expo-barcode-scanner`

If your version of Expo is 33, you should download it individually.

You can run `expo install expo-barcode-scanner`

You must request `permission` to access the user's camera before attempting to get it. To do this, you will want to use the `Permissions` API. You can see this in practice in the following example.

**Basic Example**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

export default class BarcodeScannerExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    scanned: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync();
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  };

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        }}>
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        />

        {scanned && (
          <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ scanned: true });
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };
}
```

**props**

- **onBarCodeScanned (function)**

Callback that is invoked when a bar code has been successfully scanned. The callback is provided with an object of the shape `{ type: BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType, data: string }`, where the type refers to the bar code type that was scanned and the data is the information encoded in the bar code (in this case of QR codes, this is often a URL). See `BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType` for supported values.

- **barCodeTypes (Array)**

An array of bar code types. Usage: `BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.<codeType>` where `codeType` is one of the listed above. Default: all supported bar code types. For example:

```
barCodeTypes={[BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]}
```

- **type (string)**

  -- Camera facing. Use one of `BarCodeScanner.Constants.Type`. Use either `Type.front` or `Type.back`. Same as `Camera.Constants.Type`. Default: `Type.back`.

**Note:** Passing `undefined` to the `onBarCodeScanned` prop will result in no scanning. This can be used to effectively "pause" the scanner so that it doesn't continually scan even after data has been retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using expo, you will have npx. You can run any react-native command with npx. Hence:

npx react-native link react-native-camera